# how to install mysql ha using helm 3.0

Tags: mysql, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I am install MySQL HA follow by [this doc](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/incubator/mysqlha):

```
./helm install report incubator/mysqlha -n middleware
```

but the result like this:

```
[dolphin@MeowK8SMaster1 linux-amd64]$ ./helm repo update
Hang tight while we grab the latest from your chart repositories...
...Successfully got an update from the "traefik" chart repository
...Successfully got an update from the "stable" chart repository
Update Complete. ⎈ Happy Helming!⎈
[dolphin@MeowK8SMaster1 linux-amd64]$ ./helm install report incubator/mysqlha -n middleware
Error: failed to download "incubator/mysqlha" (hint: running `helm repo update` may help)
[dolphin@MeowK8SMaster1 linux-amd64]$
```

what should I do install mysql HA?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your must first install the **repository** on which the *mysqlh* chart resides:

```
helm repo add incubator https://kubernetes-charts-incubator.storage.googleapis.com
```

Then run `helm repo update.` After that installation should succeed.

When unsure where to find helm chart repos, check Helm Hub: https://hub.helm.sh/charts/incubator/mysqlha

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](https://github.com/helm/charts#how-do-i-enable-the-incubator-repository) enable `incubator` repository

```
helm repo add incubator https://kubernetes-charts-incubator.storage.googleapis.com
```

And then run `helm repo update` followed by `install`

```
./helm install report incubator/mysqlha -n middleware
```

Answer (score 0):

add incubator repo:

```
 helm repo add incubator https://kubernetes-charts-incubator.storage.googleapis.com
```